# Display videos only from specific folder

Tags: android, listview, directory

How do I display videos in listview only fron specific folder?
I use MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. but it gets all videos from the gallery.
I don't want to add videos to the gallery. How do I specify the URI to a specific folder?

Comment: hey did you get the answer of this question?

Answer (score 0):

See [Uri.fromFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile%28java.io.File%29).  The `File` object would be a directory or file that you want to convert to a `Uri`.

Comment: Do i put this Uri in my query: Uri vidUri = Uri.fromFile(vidDir); 
cursor = managedQuery(vidUri, DB_columns, null, null, null); 
Is this right?